# Colocar un select option dentro un div con d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, d3-v4.js

Estoy tratando de colocar una lista desplegable (con `select` y `option`) dentro de un `div` y un SVG usando d3.js, pero no funciona y el `select` no se ve. No sé si son las propiedades o el motivo por el que ocurre. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Éste es el código que estoy usando:

> Nota: el código proviene de una pregunta que fue anteriormente borrada y también está disponible en [este JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwuwnxtn/).

```js
var data = [
  {"id":1,"text":"LAND1"},
  {"id":2,"text":"LAND2"},
  {"id":1,"text":"LAND3"}
];

var vis = d3.select(".dashboard")
            .select("#sowing")
            .append("div")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("id", "chartID")
            .attr("class", "boxing")
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 540 250")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 550 / 2 + "," + 300 / 2 + ")");

var select = vis.append('select')
                .attr("name", "dept-list")
                .attr("class", "form-control");

var options = select.selectAll('option')
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append('option')
                    .text(function(d) {
                      return d.text;
                    })
                    .attr("value", function(d) {
                      return d.id;
                    });
```

```css
#chartID {
  border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<section class="content">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="dashboard">
    <div id="sowing"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está al hacer esto:

```
var vis = d3.select(".dashboard")
            .select("#sowing")
            .append("div")
            .append("svg")
            ....
```

La variable `vis` no contiene un `div` sino un `svg` que es el último elemento que se añadió. Entonces el `select` se está poniendo dentro de un `svg` y no se muestra, porque los elementos HTML no son propios de SVG, entonces se ignoran y no se muestran (aunque si miras el código, verás que sí están ahí).

Una posibilidad sería mover el `select` a fuera del `svg` y posicionarlo de manera absoluta donde quieras. Entonces ya podrías colocarlo encima del SVG y se vería bien (aunque técnicamente no estará dentro del SVG).

Otra alternativa sería utilizar [`foreignObject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject). En SVG puedes colocar código no propio de SVG (por ejemplo HTML) dentro de un SVG usando `foreignObject` (que se traduce literalmente como objeto foráneo o extraño) y se ejecutará de la manera apropiada. Entonces tendrías que poner el `select` dentro de un `foreignObject` en el SVG para que entonces sí se interprete.

Sólo tendrías que cambiar estas líneas de código (el resto se mantendría igual):

```
// primero coloca un foreignObject
var fo = vis.append("foreignObject")
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 100);

// y luego el select dentro del foreign object
var select = fo.append('xhtml:select')
               .attr("name", "dept-list")
               .attr("class", "form-control");
```

Nota que es muy importante que el `foreignObject` tenga un ancho y alto (mínimo de 1) o su contenido no se mostrará. Además, nota como le he puesto el prefijo `xhtml:` al `select` para que se interprete correctamente (de lo contrario no se vería).

---

El resultado completo se vería así:

```js
var data = [
  {"id":1,"text":"LAND1"},
  {"id":2,"text":"LAND2"},
  {"id":1,"text":"LAND3"}
];

var vis = d3.select(".dashboard")
            .select("#sowing")
            .append("div")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("id", "chartID")
            .attr("class", "boxing")
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 540 250")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 550 / 2 + "," + 300 / 2 + ")");

var fo = vis.append("foreignObject")
            .attr("width", 1)
            .attr("height", 1);
          
var select = fo.append('xhtml:select')
               .attr("name", "dept-list")
               .attr("class", "form-control");


var options = select.selectAll('option')
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append('option')
                    .text(function(d) {
                      return d.text;
                    })
                    .attr("value", function(d) {
                      return d.id;
                    });
```

```css
#chartID {
  border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<section class="content">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="dashboard">
    <div id="sowing"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```